# Delete Function deletes everything instead of deleting one item

Tags: javascript

I've created a Function to delete a product from a webshop cart. But there is a problem. If I want to delete the last element, this is fine. But if there are 2 elements or more and I delete the first item, it's like
my function is repeats itself and deletes every item from the cart.

Can you help me out please? I want my function to stop when one item has been deleted.

```js
/*This Function is here because of the unknown number of products in the cart
  so i can reuse the creation of all elements if i need
  All the JS elements have their own description to make the code more understandble*/
  const cartProducts = (productStorage, product) => {

    //------Create constant article who gonna contein all my elements------

    let article = document.createElement('article');
    article.classList.add('cart__item');
    article.setAttribute( "data-id", productStorage.id);


    let cartDivImg = document.createElement('div');
    cartDivImg.classList.add('cart__item__img');

    let cartImg = document.createElement('img');
    cartImg.setAttribute('src', product["imageUrl"]);
    cartImg.setAttribute('alt', product["altText"]);

    let cartDivContent = document.createElement('div');
    cartDivContent.classList.add('cart__item__content');

    let cartDivContentTitle = document.createElement('div');
    cartDivContentTitle.classList.add('cart__item__content__titlePrice');

    let cartName = document.createElement('h2');
    cartName.textContent = productStorage.name;

    let cartPrice = document.createElement('p');
    cartPrice.textContent = productStorage.price + " €";

    let cartDivSettings = document.createElement('div');
    cartDivSettings.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings');

    let cartDivQuantity = document.createElement('div');
    cartDivQuantity.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings__quantity');

    let cartQuantityP = document.createElement('p');
    cartQuantityP.textContent = "Qté : ";


    let cartQuantityInput = document.createElement('input');
    cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("type","number");
    cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("name","itemQuantity");
   
    cartQuantityInput.classList.add('itemQuantity');
    cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("min","1");
    cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("max","100");
    cartQuantityInput.setAttribute("value", productStorage.quantity);

  
    let cartItemDelete = document.createElement('div');
    cartItemDelete.classList.add('cart__item__content__settings__delete');
   

    let CartDeleteP = document.createElement('p');
    CartDeleteP.textContent = "Supprimer";
    CartDeleteP.classList.add('deleteItem');
    


    //Create all the elements
    article.appendChild(cartDivImg);
    cartDivImg.appendChild(cartImg);
    article.appendChild(cartDivContent);
    cartDivContent.appendChild(cartDivContentTitle);
    cartDivContentTitle.appendChild(cartName);
    cartDivContentTitle.appendChild(cartPrice);
    cartDivContent.appendChild(cartDivSettings);
    cartDivSettings.appendChild(cartDivQuantity);
    cartDivQuantity.appendChild(cartQuantityP);
    cartDivQuantity.appendChild(cartQuantityInput);
    cartDivSettings.appendChild(cartItemDelete);
    cartItemDelete.appendChild(CartDeleteP);
    cartItems.appendChild(article);


    removeItem();
    emptyCart();
    qteChange();

  }
  
  
    let cartStructure = [];

  if (productLocalStorage === null){

    console.log("I'm Empty");
  } 
  // Loop "forEach" who create all the elements i need in my cart
  else{

  productLocalStorage.forEach(productLocalStorage => {

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products/" + productLocalStorage.id) 
      //Catch data i need from the api 

      .then(data =>data.json())
      .then(product=>{
      console.log(product);
      cartProducts(productLocalStorage, product);

    });

  });
```

```js
  let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
  function removeItem() {
    let removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");
    for (let i = 0; i < removeBtn.length; i++) {
      removeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
  
        let articleSupp = removeBtn[i].closest("article");

        articleSupp.remove();
        deleteItemSelected(i);
        alert("This Item will be remove from your cart");
        window.location.href = "cart.html";
  
        // Actualising the total amount of item in the cart

      });
      //This Function 
      function deleteItemSelected(index) {
        products.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
      }
    }
  }
```

The Html:

```html
            <article class="cart__item" data-id="{product-ID}">
                <div class="cart__item__img">
                  <img src="../images/product01.jpg" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
                </div>
                <div class="cart__item__content">
                  <div class="cart__item__content__titlePrice">
                    <h2>Name product</h2>
                    <p>42,00 €</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
                      <p>Qté : </p>
                      <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="42">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
                      <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
```

Comment: Requesting clarification: If you have 5 items and you delete the first, then all are deleted but if you delete last then only last is deleted and you get 4 items? Also can you include a bit of HTML till `article`.

Comment: i've updated my post and post the html in question
and yes, if i have 5 items, if i delete only the last one, the others aren't delete
but only the last one.

The problem is just when i delete the first one, that delete the others
thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution. For those who will have the same issue, you can easily resolve the problem which is that all of my elements are created in my function.

My function is called in a loop that can create all the elements which are in my cart. So I can only call my delete function in my function "cartProducts".

To make my delete function not repeat herself, I have to use:

```js
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

In here:

```js
removeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();//here *******************

        let articleSupp = removeBtn[i].closest("article");
        
        articleSupp.remove();
        deleteItemSelected(i);
        alert("This Item will be remove from your cart");
        window.location.href = "cart.html";
  
        // Actualising the total amount of item in the cart    
      });
```

So now my function will delete my element and will stop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You should take out the deleteItemSelected function from loop(for)! and . like this:

```
function removeItem() {

   let removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");

   function deleteItemSelected(index) {
       products.splice(index, 1);
       localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
   }

   for (let i = 0; i < removeBtn.length; i++) {
        removeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
           e.preventDefault();

           let articleSupp = removeBtn[i].closest("article");

           articleSupp.remove();
           deleteItemSelected(i);
           alert("This Item will be remove from your cart");
           window.location.href = "cart.html";

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i've tried but that not working for me
i've update my post to make you see how i created all my elements
and when i call my function